# how to pass date in url in asynctask android

Tags: android

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat mdformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy / MM / dd ");
String strDate =mdformat.format(calendar.getTime()).toString();
String  link = "http://avin.ashainfosystems.com/cw/orders.php?orders=" + name + "&order_id=" + strDate;
```

when i pass strDate it throws 
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

Comment: Please post your code where you trying to compare strings error is not coming in posted code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried. It doesn't give null pointer exception.
strDate contain "/",space. So please encode the strDate when concatenate with url.

```
String  link = "http://avin.ashainfosystems.com/cw/orders.php?orders= &order_id=" + URLEncoder.encode(strDate, "utf-8");
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

**.toString()** not needed

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
.....
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    String strDate = df.format(c.getTime());
......
```